# Linux distribution for beginners

Tags: linux

what is the best linux distribution for Beginner?currently I am trying to get familiar with solus Gnome

Comment: Sorry, there is no *best*. We have no idea what your criteria are and you will have to tell us. Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Comment: Linux Mint is generally considered to be a good beginners distro

Answer (score 4):

[Linux Mint](https://linuxmint.com/download.php) is great. I use it on my PC and my laptop and I have no complains. After some configuration it looks gorgeous too.

Comment: I installed Mint on my mothers computer and never heard any complaints, and she **is** a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on:

1. where you are coming from (Windows/OSX/etc)
2. what you are a beginner at (system or software development/Non-CS academic research/everyday use/etc)

My one-fits-all answer to your question would be an Ubuntu version to familiarize yourself with nuts and bolts of Linux and then depart from there based on your specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easiest or best. However as a personal recommendation I'd say give 
[Elementary OS](https://elementary.io/nl/) a try, because:

- It has a real clean and easy interface inspired by Mac. This will make it easier to use because of familiarity.
- It has a simple [graphic software installer  / package manager](https://appcenter.elementary.io/) with applications that fit the style of the OS.
- It has [support on the network site you are already familiar with](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/)
- Based on Ubuntu, which is the most well known distro and is often used as a synonym with Linux itself.
- [And some more subtle benefits](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-linux-distros-programmers/)

However if you really like the MS Windows interface you might be better of using Ubuntu + GKT + [this Windows theme](https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1013482/)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from personal experience with different Linux distributions for 12+ years now, I'd vote for Ubuntu and Linux Mint.

Easy to install, both distributions are very user friendly and have almost everything you need in terms of apps to begin your Linux experience. Never had an issue with either distribution.